# Redirect loop only hompage when redirect from http to https

Tags: redirection

I am trying to use Varnish + Pound, when using https everything is OK except only hompage has redirect loop. The others page are OK. 
Here is my rewrite rule in `.htaccess` file.

Please help me with redirect loop

```
 RewriteEngine On 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Comment: There might be an existing redirect somewhere else.

Comment: I don't know where, is there a solution to find out where it is?

Comment: your apache vhosts?